# How to print different parts of a list on new line in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have two lists, one is of a known length and the other is a random length:

```
MyList1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5],[5, 6, 7, 8]].
MyList2 = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6 ]
```

I need to print the second one in the following way, where 3 lines is for the number of objects in the first list:

```
[1, 2, 3] 
[4, 5]
[6]
```

The problem is that I don't know the exact length of this list and the sizes of the lines may not be equal.

I got stuck on doing it with `for loop`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It's unclear how the first list relates to the second. Are you splitting the second list into segments of length equal to length of the second list divided by the length of the first list? Or something else? Can you give us more input/output examples?

Comment: What does it mean  "I don't know the exact length of this list"? Cannot you use len(MyList2)?

Comment: Sorry to misguide you a little. 
list1 consists of lists of integers of a random length, like that [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5],[5, 6, 7, 8]]. I appended some derivatives of these numbers to list2 and I need to print it so that the first line has 3 digits, second line has two digits and the third line has four.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment, I think the following will work for you:

```
>>> l1
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
>>> l2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> i,s=0,0
>>> while s < len(l2):
        print l2[s:s+len(l1[i])]
        s += len(l1[i])
        i += 1
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i figured out how to solve my problem!

Comment: @Sharky .. Glad you figured it yourself so my answer will help you to confirm that..:)

Answer (score 1):

A `while` loop will do the trick better.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 ]

start = 0
while start < len(list2):
    print list2[start:start+len(list1)]
    start += len(list1)
```

Comment: Thanks for help! But what should I do if i need the length of the printed lines not to be equal?

Answer (score 0):

If you're curious how to use a `for` loop:

```
step_size = int(len(list2)/len(list1))
for i in range(0, len(list1) - 1):
    start = i * step_size
    end = start + step_size
    print(list2[start:end])
print(list2[len(list1)*step_size - step_size:])
```

The `print` after the loop prints the last chunk, which might be a different size than the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can try generator function like this,

```
my_list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6 ]
my_list2 = [1, 2, 3]

def make_list(lst1, lst2):
    item_count = len(lst1) / len(lst2)
    for ix in range(0, len(lst1), item_count):
        yield lst1[ix:ix + item_count]

print list(make_list(my_list1, my_list2))
```